# Apache ExpiresDefault A0 does not work

Tags: apache2.4

I am setting up apache headers and do not want to cache PHP, CGI, Python, or any dynamic files.

I am using the server: Debian 9

I have added this config:

```
# No caching for dynamic files
<filesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl|htm)$">
    ExpiresDefault A0
    Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</filesMatch>
```

But following error is shown:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 86 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/headers.conf: Invalid command 'ExpiresDefault', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration Action '-t' failed.
```

How do I solve this error?

Comment: Why do you think that is not working? Syntax looks fine to me but please explain the problem if you want help with a solution. Have you turned on ExpiresActive flag (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresactive)?

Comment: AH00526: Syntax error on line 86 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/headers.conf:
Invalid command 'ExpiresDefault', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action '-t' failed.

Comment: I am using this Apache configuration file https://github.com/gregrickaby/The-Perfect-Apache-Configuration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable mod_expiries.

Uncomment the following line from httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
```

Or if on Debian based system then enable it with the following command:

```
a2enmod expires
```